# Possible Bug in DiscretizeRegion with Option MaxCellMeasure

Tags: bugs, computational-geometry

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

Consider the following `ImplicitRegion`:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 16, {x, y, z}];
```

We can discretize it using `DiscretizeRegion`

```
dr = DiscretizeRegion[reg]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To get finer triangles the option `MaxCellMeasure` is available, only it does nothing when used.

```
DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> #}] & /@ {0.1, 0.05}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course using one of the `Graphics` primitives

```
DiscretizeRegion[Ball[], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> #}] & /@ {0.1, 0.05}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see that it works fine. I'm on **Windows 8.1**, can anyone confirm this on other platforms? Confirmed on **Linux** via the Wolfram Programming Cloud.

Comment: Tip: you can test on Linux using http://www.wolframcloud.com/

Comment: @Szabolcs, Thanks nice tip. But it's so painful using it :)

Comment: Using the other quality control options, `PrecisionGoal`, `AccuracyGoal`,`MeshQualityGoal`, and `MeshRefinementFunction` on the `ImplicitRegion` similarly has no effect.

Comment: Have you reported it?

Comment: @Szabolcs. Yes. Hopefully more people will report it, since that'll get their attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit: Wolfram Technical Support has confirmed this as a bug**

The only workaround I know is to turn the `MeshRegion` into a `BoundaryMeshRegion` and triangulate the resulting mesh object:

```
dr = DiscretizeRegion[reg, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.05}];
```

Then:

```
TriangulateMesh[BoundaryMeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[dr], MeshCells[dr, 2]], 
                                               MaxCellMeasure -> #] & /@ {0.1, 0.005}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It seems like another workaround is to repeatedly apply `DiscretizeRegion` which is definitely a weird approach. ( Thanks to Michael E2 )

```
Rest @ NestList[DiscretizeRegion, reg, 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `DiscretizeRegion[dr, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 0.01}]` produces similar results.  Note that the outer function (`DiscretizeRegion` or `TriangulateMesh`) subdivides a mesh region and does not attempt to approximate the implicit region.  Perhaps someone will come along and let us know whether implicit regions can be approximated with arbitrary precision.

Comment: @MichaelE2, That's an interesting find. So basically, One has to discretize the result of `DiscretizedRegion` to see the effect. That makes no sense.

Comment: @MichaelE2, This bug is also present in `DiscretizeGraphics` and has been sort-of confirmed by @user21.

Comment: Well, this is a bug (or lack of implementation?) and by all means, you should report this.

Comment: @user21, I already reported it and linked to this page.

Answer (score 1):

> To get finer triangles the option MaxCellMeasure is available, only it
>   does nothing when used.

This is fixed in 10.0.2. on windows 7, 64 bit

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: But the same bug in `DiscretizeGraphics` was never fixed. I just stumbled upon it (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/238758/change-mesh-density-of-graphics3d-object-made-of-triangles/238759#238759)