# MaxCellMeasure fails in 3D?

Tags: differential-equations, computational-geometry, geometry

**Question**

> How come [`MaxCellMeasure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaxCellMeasure.html) works in 2D but fails in 3D?

Indeed if I try

```
Table[DiscretizeRegion[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}], 
   MaxCellMeasure -> res] // {#, ByteCount[#]} &, {res, {1, 0.1, 
   0.01}}]// Transpose
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It works as expected (i.e. the quality of the mesh, and its size increases).
Whereas this does not

```
Table[DiscretizeRegion[
    ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, y, z}], 
    MaxCellMeasure -> res] // {#, ByteCount[#]} &, {res, {1, 0.1, 
    0.01}}] // Transpose
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let me apologize in advance if this is a RTFM question. The documentation is such a maze on these new (cool) Mesh features.

**Comment**

Note that this fails but only partially:

```
Table[DiscretizeRegion[
    ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, y, z}], 
    MaxCellMeasure -> res] // {#, ByteCount[#]} &, {res, {1, 0.1, 
    0.01}}] // Transpose
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

which might be a clue??

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56613/possible-bug-in-discretizeregion-with-option-maxcellmeasure.  See if the workaround there works for you. (It says the bug has been fixed as of 10.0.2, but...)

Comment: Try replacing `MaxCellMeasure -> res` with `MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> res}`

Answer (score 4):

As @RunnyKine mentioned, Try replacing `MaxCellMeasure -> res` with `MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> res}` seems to partially work:

```
Table[DiscretizeRegion[
    ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, y, z}], 
    MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> res}] // {#, 
     ByteCount[#]} &, {res, {1, 0.1, 0.01}}] // Transpose
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]