# Is there any way to improve the result of DiscretizeRegion on this 3D ImplicitRegion?

Tags: regions, finite-element-method, computational-geometry

Consider two definitions of a cubic region,

```
a = 5;
region1 = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= a && 0 <= y <= a && 0 <= z <= a, {x, y, z}];
region2 = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, a, a}];
RegionPlot3D /@ {region1, region2}
```

[image]

We can test whether certain points fall inside the regions

```
{0, 0, 0} ∈ region1
{0, 0, 0} ∈ region2
(* True *)
(* True *)
```

But when I try to make a `DiscretizeRegion` object for use in an FEM `NDSolve` calculation, one is clearly better than the other:

```
{region1dis, region2dis} = DiscretizeRegion /@ {region1, region2}
```

[image]

This is clear visually as well as in region tests,

```
# ∈ region1dis & /@ {{0, 0, 0}, {.04, .04, .04}, {.4, .4, .4}}
# ∈ region2dis & /@ {{0, 0, 0}, {.04, .04, .04}, {.4, .4, .4}}
(* {False, False, True} *)
(* {True, True, True} *)
```

I can't find an option for `DiscretizeRegion` that fixes this.  Not `AccuracyGoal` or `PrecisionGoal` or `MaxCellMeasure`, or any of the `Method`s listed in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56613/9490), [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92292/9490), or [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85839/9490).  If this is a duplicate of one of those, my apologies

Answer (score 4):

This is a tangential answer to your question, but perhaps it may be of interest nonetheless, in the spirit of providing an alternative approach.

In the case of a cubic region you may be interested in using the bounding box option to `DiscretizeRegion`, rather than trying to coax it to include all the edges (which I was not yet able to do either).

For instance:

```
region3dis = DiscretizeRegion[
   FullRegion[3], {{0, a}, {0, a}, {0, a}},
   MaxCellMeasure -> 20
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
# ∈ region3dis & /@ {{0, 0, 0}, {.04, .04, .04}, {.4, .4, .4}}
(* Out: {True, True, True} *)
```

Incidentally, this works well with the FEM element mesh generators as well:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
ToElementMesh[FullRegion[3], {{0, 5}, {0, 5}, {0, 5}}, MaxCellMeasure -> 20]

(* Out: ElementMesh[{{0., 5.}, {0., 5.}, {0., 5.}}, {HexahedronElement["<" 8 ">"]}] *)

%["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]