# Simple triangular meshes of primitive shapes

Tags: graphics, geometry, mesh

I'd like to generate triangular meshes or a cylinder and sphere primitives as part of a lattice meshing program I am writing to experiment with Mathematica. Consider the following snippet:

```
{p1, p2, r} = {{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, 0.5};
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Cylinder[{p1, p2}, r]]
FullForm[%]
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Sphere[p1, r], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01]
FullForm[%]
```

I have 2 questions

1. For the sphere: How can I extract the coordinates and connectivities I can see in the output of the second `FullForm` call into separate list of vertices and connectivities. I guess I need to do some magic to extract correct parts of the expression.
2. For the cylinder: How can I convert the polygons defining the caps and the quadrilaterals around the body into triangles and then extract the triangles into vertices and connectivity lists as for the cylinder

[image] [image]

Comment: How odd. It seems that even with a ridiculously small setting of `MaxCellMeasure`, the cylinder remains untriangulated...

Comment: @J.M. `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics` doesn't triangulate flat surfaces (in contrast to `DiscretizeGraphics`). It is simply unnecessary for boundary approximation.

Comment: Anyway: look up `MeshCoordinates[]` and `MeshCells[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Amazing, that's exactly what I want :) I knew it had to be something easy, but I didn't find those so I was thinking I would need some combination of `Position[...,Heads->True]` and `Part[...]`, this is much easier though, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[Cylinder[{p1, p2}, r], 
  RegionBounds[Cylinder[{p1, p2}, r]]]
bmesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

More information can be found on the ref page of [ToBoundaryMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToBoundaryMesh.html).

Comment: Nice, thanks for contributing, your solution is very concise! I slightly prefer my own though since for my lattice application I wanted to generate lots of bars each with a small number of elements. I should have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: @mkm, no worries if you want a more complicated solution I can come with one - not a very typical request though ;-)

Comment: haha, sure. The solution can have more elements, but the cylinder needs less, man! :)

Answer (score 2):

For the first half of Question 2, use `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`. For some reason it's important to avoid machine-precision `Real` numbers. Instead of `0.5`, use arbitrary-precision `Rational` `1/2`.

```
{p1, p2, r} = {{-1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}, 1/2};
reg = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cylinder[{p1, p2}, r]]
```

[image: triangulated cylindrical surface]

And yeah, as pointed out by [J. M.♦](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) in the comment, `MeshCoordinates` and `MeshCells` are for the rest of your questions.

```
Array[Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[reg], MeshCells[reg, #]]] &, 3, 0]
```

[image: extracting mesh elements]

Comment: This is cool, and simpler than my suggestion, can you make the mesh coarser?

Comment: `MaxCellMeasure` still [doesn't work well](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56613/possible-bug-in-discretizeregion-with-option-maxcellmeasure), so basically no.

Answer (score 1):

Using the tip from the comments I figured out the following solution

```
bdg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Cylinder[{p1, p2}, r]];

(* Triangulate boundary quads and cap polygons *)
cylinderPolyAll = Map[(#[[-1]]) &, MeshCells[bdg, 2], 1];
cylinderQuad = Select[cylinderPolyAll, (Length[#] == 4) &];
cylinderQuadE = 
  Flatten[Map[({#[[{1, 2, 3}]], #[[{3, 4, 1}]]}) &, cylinderQuad], 
   1];
cylinderCaps = Select[cylinderPolyAll, (Length[#] != 4) &];
cylinderCapsE = 
  Flatten[Map[(Table[{#[[1]], #[[i + 1]], #[[i + 2]]}, {i, 1, 
        Length[#] - 2}]) &, cylinderCaps], 1];

(* Vertices and connectivity of triangulated cylinder *)
cylinderE = Join[cylinderQuadE, cylinderCapsE];
cylinderV = MeshCoordinates[bdg];

(* Visualise triangulated cylinder *)
cylinderVE = With[{v = cylinderV, e = cylinderE}, Table[
    {v[[e[[i, 1]]]], v[[e[[i, 2]]]], v[[e[[i, 3]]]]},
    {i, 1, Length[cylinderE]}]];
Graphics3D[Map[Polygon[#] &, cylinderVE]];
```

[image]

The sphere case is easier